# What is the slope of the line tangent to the graph of the function $f(x)=\ln(\sin^2x+3)$ at the point where $x=\frac\pi4$?

Tags: calculus

What method would you use to solve this problem?

> What is the slope of the line tangent to the graph of the function $f(x)=\ln(\sin^2x+3)$ at the point where $x=\pi/3$?

I've tried taking the derivative of the function and plugging in $\pi/3$ but I can't seem to reach a solution. I keep getting the square root of a negative number...

Comment: I'd take the derivative and evaluate it at \pi/3.

Comment: show what derivative you got, please

Comment: You shouldn't have any square root at all.

Comment: The derivative of ln x is 1/x.  The derivative of sin x is cos x.  derivative of x^2 is 2x.  Use the chain rule a few times.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the steps.
See if you can follow them.

$f(x)
=\ln(\sin^2(x)+3)
$.
Therefore

$\begin{align}\\
f'(x)
&=(\ln(\sin^2(x)+3))'\\
&=\frac{(\sin^2(x)+3)'}{\sin^2(x)+3}
&\text{ since } (\ln g(x))' = \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\\
&=\frac{(\sin^2(x))'+(3)'}{\sin^2(x)+3}
&\text{ since } (g(x)+h(x))' = g'(x)+h'(x)\\
&=\frac{(\sin^2(x))'}{\sin^2(x)+3}
&\text{ since the derivative of a constant is zero}\\
&=\frac{2(\sin(x))'\sin(x)}{\sin^2(x)+3}
&\text{ since } (g^2(x))' = 2g'(x)g(x)\\
&=\frac{2\cos(x)\sin(x)}{\sin^2(x)+3}
&\text{ since }  (\sin(x))' = \cos(x)\\
\end{align}
$

Now,
you substitute
$x = \frac{\pi}{3}
$.

Comment: Was \frac instead of \dfrac intentional here?

Comment: Nah. dfrac probably would have been better. I start with something and copy and paste to get the next line.